# How to replace UISegmentedControl with THSegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using [`UISegmentControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex) objects on the `Storyboard` but it only supports selecting a single segment,

[image]

So I found an alternative that is [`THSegmentedControl`](https://github.com/tayhalla/THSegmentedControl). Now the problem is that I can't replace `UISegmentControl` class in the Identity Inspector, it only shows `UISegmentedControl`:

[image]

Project Navigator View:

[image]

So how can I use `THSegmentedControl` instead?

I just copied the two files `THSegmentedControl.h/m` is there any other needed setup?

Comment: Have you tried clean project, quiet xcode, reopen xcode and then build, then assign class?

Comment: @ViralSavaj still the same result.

Comment: Have you set up a `UISegmentControl` class via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`THSegmentedControl` is not a subclass of `UISegmentedControl` but directly of `UIControl`:

```
@interface THSegmentedControl : UIControl
```

You will not be able to set a `UISegmentedControl` IB object with this control. Instead, replace the IB object with a `UIView` object, and then set its class to `THSegmentedControl`.